Разделить строку на гласные и согласные
Есть ли в Python простой способ разделить строку на отдельные сегменты с гласными и согласными символами?
Пример
на входе:
"ОСТА'ТЬСЯ"

(симовл ' после гласной обозначает ударение на неё)
на выходе получаем:
["О", "СТ", "А'", "ТЬС", "Я"]

То есть слово получается разделено на сегменты, в каждом из которых либо только гласные, идущие в слове подряд, либо только согласные, идущие в слове подряд.

Регулярки, но буквы напишешь сам.

import re

def split_consonants(text):
    # Регулярное выражение для поиска кластеров гласных (включая ударение) или согласных
    pattern = r"[аАеЕёЁиИоОуУыЫэЭюЮяЯ']+|[^аАеЕёЁиИоОуУыЫэЭюЮяЯ']+"
    segments = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return segments

text = "ОСТА'ТЬСЯ"
print(split_consonants(text))

